# How can I iterate over my list in jinja2 flask app?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, jinja2

I have the following code:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block app_content %}

    <table class="table table-hover table-striped">

        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th style="text-align: center">Hostname</th>
            <th style="text-align: center">IP_address</th>
            <th style="text-align: center">uptime</th>
            <th style="text-align: center">location</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <ul>
            {% for canary in newlist %}
              <li>{{ canary }}</li>
            {% endfor %}
            </ul>
            

        </tbody>
    </table>

{% endblock %}
```

How do i make it so that each of my appended items from my python file are under each separate column?

Currently it just lists my list.

This is my return function

```
def canaries_up_time(results):

    results = results.json()
    #print(json.dumps(my_dict, indent=3))
    newlist = []
    for item in results['devices']:
        
        newlist.append(item.get("name"))
        newlist.append(item.get("uptime"))
        newlist.append(item.get("ip_address"))
        newlist.append(item.get("location"))

    return newlist
```

Comment: I don't see in your function any routing neither the render template of your HTML. have a look to my answer carefully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the canary items into a dictionary, pass that into the template and render it like so:

```
{% for canary in newlist %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{canary.name}}</td>
        <td>{{canary.uptime}}</td>
        <td>{{canary.ip_address}}</td>
        <td>{{canary.location}}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

###### Edit, added snippet

Where the dictionary keys are named like the variables above.
Newlist now is a list of dictionaries, you could make it like this:

```
newlist = []
for item in results['devices']:
    newlist.append({'name':item.get("name"), 'ip_address':item.get("ip_address"), etc etc etc})
```

Comment: Cannot connect to Canaries error: 'dict' object has no attribute 'append'

Comment: Added a snippet of code above.

Answer (score 0):

In your .py you need to pass newlist as a return:

```
@app.route("/")
def index():
    newlist = ['a', 'b', 'c']
    return render_template('index.html', newlist=newlist)
```

Let me know if this solves your problem.

Comment: it doesnt, thats not it, it will print it fine in a block of text which im trying to avoid

Comment: show how is your list and what it's the output you expect.

Comment: i just want each of my 4 items to be printed nicely in a table (name, uptime, ip address, location), currently its just the out of newlist...

Comment: It should help as I said before if you share your list and output expected. Otherwise is hard to help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you need your items in columns, you need "tr" and "td" inside the "tbody", not the "li" tag.
And I don't know, how your "newlist" looks like, if you can post that, someone might give you a better answer.